# how to save image to photoalbum when there are many layers in the image?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3

Im having problem to my image when saving, there are different layers like drawing view & my textfield above my image but I don't want my layers to be add to subview because if i added it to my subview my drawing view, textfield cannot be edit again since it is attached already on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 CGSize sizePic = CGSizeMake(320, 440);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sizePic);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *imagePic = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imagePic, nil, nil, nil);
```

I was to able to figured on my own. :)